# find max/min days and get first differences of certain columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the structure of

Col1 = Date
Col2 = ID_Product
Col3 = Price
Col4 = Units_Sold

My table name is "tbl"

If I want to find the max and min date for each ID_Product, and find the change in price where Units_Sold is >0, how exactly woudl i execute this query in an organized and "correct way"

My version right now is quite convoluted looking and there must be a better way to do something such as this.

This is basically what I am trying to do but it is not behaving as I would expect:

```
select * 
from 
(select id,min(dt) as dt,fields from table where field>0 group by id,dt) as a
left join
(select id,max(dt) as dt,field from table where field>0 group by id,dt) as b
on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ORDER BY and LIMIT or look into the SQL MAX() and MIN() functions with some sort of subquery.  I'll provide a non-language specific example to the first way and direct you to a question that does it the second way.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

Not sure what language you're using:

```
    for (products p)
    {
        pNewest = executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
        pOldest = executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1");
        double difference = Math.abs(pNewest["price"] - pOldest["price"]);
    }
```

Second way: 
[SQL Server: how to imitate oracle keep dense_rank query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756717/sql-server-how-to-imitate-oracle-keep-dense-rank-query)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp