# Get the employee wages within an effective date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to get the calculate the EMPLOYEE Salary within a given date range in sql server

My data is

`EMPLOYEE RATE` table:

```
EMPL_ID EFFECTIVE_DATE  WAGE    
101        5/23/2015    20  
101        6/2/2016      30
```

`PROJECT` table:

```
EMPL_ID HRS_DT  PROJECT_ID HOURS
101     1/1/2015   10001        8
101     1/2/2015   10001        8
101     1/3/2015   10001        8
 ...      ....      .....       ....
101     6/2/2016     ....        ...
```

Expected result:

```
EMPL_ID HRS_DT      PROJ_ID HR    WAGES
101     1/1/2015    10001   8      20
101     1/2/2015    10001   8      20
101     1/3/2015    10001   8      20
...      ....        ...   ...
....     6/2/2016                   30
```

Comment: You say SQL Server, but tag Oracle. Which product are you using?

Comment: This is a very basic SQL query.  Please use Google and look up how to do this, give it a try, and post any problems that you come across while attempting to solve it yourself.

Comment: With the data you've shown that looks trivial. But that's with wages changing every day and a one-to-one relationship between the dates in the two tables. Do you really have gaps between the wage changes, and project records in those gaps, and you want to find the appropriate wage value for those dates too - i.e. figuring out what the wage would have been on any given date?

Comment: Yes their are gaps within the data .it can vary from 2 months upto 1 year of difference within the effective dates

Comment: So change your example data to show that, and explain the requirement clearly. Not necessarily such large gaps, but just to give the idea of what your real data looks like, and what the expected output is with gaps.

Comment: this is the correct data .Hope this helps

Comment: Are all the project dates supposed to be in 2016? You still have clarified if this is Oracle or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you can join the two tables on the `empl_id` column and ignore any `employee_rate` rows where the effective data is later than the project date:

```
select p.empl_id, p.hrs_dt, p.project_id, p.hours, er.wage
from project p
join employee_rate er on er.empl_id = p.empl_id
and er.effective_date <= p.hrs_dt;

   EMPL_ID HRS_DT     PROJECT_ID      HOURS       WAGE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       101 2016-01-01      10001          8         20
       101 2016-01-02      10001          8         20
       101 2016-01-03      10001          8         20
       101 2016-06-01      10001          8         20
...
       101 2016-06-02      10001          8         30
       101 2016-06-02      10001          8         20
```

... but as you can see that gives multiple results once you've had a wage change. So you only want to keep the wage value from the last record, where 'last' is the most recent of those that are before the project hours date. You can use an analytic function like `row_number()` to decide which record that is, using a subquery and then filtering to find row 1 - which will have the latest effective date:

```
select empl_id, hrs_dt, project_id, hours, wage
from (
  select p.empl_id, p.hrs_dt, p.project_id, p.hours, er.wage,
    row_number() over (partition by p.empl_id, p.hrs_dt
      order by er.effective_date desc) as rn
  from project p
  join employee_rate er on er.empl_id = p.empl_id
  and er.effective_date <= p.hrs_dt
) tmp
where rn = 1;

   EMPL_ID HRS_DT     PROJECT_ID      HOURS       WAGE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       101 2016-01-01      10001          8         20
       101 2016-01-02      10001          8         20
       101 2016-01-03      10001          8         20
...
       101 2016-06-01      10001          8         20
       101 2016-06-02      10001          8         30
```

Tested in Oracle as that was the original question tag, but this should work in SQL Server too.

Comment: Thanks .But I have to do it in Sql server

Comment: So why have you tagged the question as Oracle 11g, and ignored requests to clarify what you are using? [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10756717/266304).

Comment: sorry just posting in multiple forums got it wrong.Thanks

Comment: @user6167232 - updated with a version that should work in both databases, but I can't test it in SQL Server.