# Is there a way to only return certain values if specific conditions are meet in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to solve a business problem.  The database has commission rates assigned by the warehouse and item group.  However, occasionally we assign commission by warehouse, item group, and client.  In most cases I just need to return the commission for the warehouse and item group, but when there is a client assigned to a specific commission rate I would like to return that value instead of the standard (warehouse and item group).  Right now my query returns two commission values one for (warehouse and item group) and the other for (warehouse, item group, and customer).  Ideally, I want to customer group to override the warehouse/item group.

Here is a sample output of what I'm getting:

```
  | BizProp | WhsCode | ItmsGrpCod | ItemCode | CardCode | U_CardCode | Qty | TotSale | CommRate | Commission |
1 | 18      | 01      | 101        | 10034    | C10187   | NULL       | 856 | 1964.61 | 0.0300   | 25.68      |
2 | 18      | 01      | 101        | 10034    | C10291   | NULL       | 900 | 2088.00 | 0.0300   | 27.00      |
3 | 18      | 01      | 101        | 10034    | C10541   | NULL       | 405 | 991.85  | 0.0300   | 12.15      |
4 | 18      | 01      | 101        | 10034    | C10541   | C10541     | 405 | 991.85  | 0.0050   | 2.025      |
5 | 18      | 01      | 102        | 10001    | C10187   | NULL       | 335 | 852.44  | 0.0300   | 10.05      |
6 | 18      | 01      | 104        | 10052    | C10291   | NULL       | 5   | 51.25   | 0.2500   | 1.25       |
```

I would like the query to return row 4 only because it has a special commission rate for that customer instead of both rows 3 and 4.  Is this even possible in SQL? or will in need to do some data transformation in excel or another tool?

Here is the CTE code I use to extract the data from a temp table, run calculations, and group the data. Is there any logic I can add to achieve the above result?

```
;WITH SalesCommission_CTE AS
(
SELECT 
        BizProp,
        WhsCode, 
        ItmsGrpCod, 
        ItemCode, 
        CardCode,
        U_CardCode,
        SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
        SUM(Price) AS Price, 
        MIN(U_CommRate) AS CommRate,
        COALESCE(SUM(Quantity * Price),NULL)  AS TotSales,  --Calc total sale amount per whs,itmgrp,cardcode
        COALESCE(SUM(Quantity * U_CommRate),NULL) AS Commission  --Calc commission rate per qty sold
FROM #TmpCustSaleRpt AS tcsr
GROUP BY 
        BizProp,            
        WhsCode, 
        ItmsGrpCod, 
        ItemCode, 
        CardCode
        ,U_CardCode
)
SELECT
        BizProp,
        WhsCode, 
        ItmsGrpCod, 
        ItemCode, 
        CardCode,
        U_CardCode,
        Quantity,  
        TotSales, 
        CommRate,
        Commission
FROM SalesCommission_CTE
    WHERE ItmsGrpCod NOT IN (109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118)
    ORDER BY
        BizProp,
        WhsCode, 
        ItmsGrpCod, 
        ItemCode, 
        CardCode
        ,U_CardCode
```

Comment: Everything is possible in SQL but I still dont understand that how you to distinguish between row 3 and row 4 ?

Comment: Hi @mohdatif the designation is on the CardCode and U_CardCode columns. On row 4 the U_CardCode value matches the CardCode value indicating a special commission rate for that customer.  In row 3 that match does not exist but the WhsCode and ItmGrpCod are the same as row 4.  It's essentially a duplicate row.

Comment: Could you not use `max(U_CardCode)` instead of `U_CardCode`  in your select?

Comment: @Twistleton I dont think so it will work because rows are not duplicate and after union you will again get both the rows as column `U_CardCode`  is unique

Comment: @mohdatif The second query must then have a subquery that the row with the null value does not returned.

Comment: @Twistleton then how other rows will be fetched because first query is already restricting it to not nulls.

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM TABLE A
 WHERE U_CardCode is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE U_CardCode is null 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM TABLE B
                    WHERE B.KEY = A.KEY)

Comment: @Twistleton thanks for the input. This appeared to work for me.  

 SELECT * FROM SalesCommission_CTE WHERE U_CardCode IS NOT NULL
 UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM SalesCommission_CTE2 AS cte2
  WHERE AND U_CardCode IS NULL 
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SalesCommission_CTE AS cte1 WHERE cte2.CardCode = cte1.U_CardCode)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work with Dense rank in Oracle.If possible could you please provide the sample data as well.

```
;WITH SalesCommission_CTE AS
(
SELECT 
        BizProp,
        WhsCode, 
        ItmsGrpCod, 
        ItemCode, 
        CardCode,
        U_CardCode,
        SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
        SUM(Price) AS Price, 
        MIN(U_CommRate) AS CommRate,
        COALESCE(SUM(Quantity * Price),NULL)  AS TotSales,  --Calc total sale amount per whs,itmgrp,cardcode
        COALESCE(SUM(Quantity * U_CommRate),NULL) AS Commission  --Calc commission rate per qty sold
FROM #TmpCustSaleRpt AS tcsr
GROUP BY 
        BizProp,            
        WhsCode, 
        ItmsGrpCod, 
        ItemCode, 
        CardCode
        ,U_CardCode
)
SELECT
        BizProp,
        WhsCode, 
        ItmsGrpCod, 
        ItemCode, 
        CardCode,
        U_CardCode,
        Quantity,  
        TotSales, 
        CommRate,
        max(Commission) keep (dense_rank first order by U_CardCode  desc null last) over (partition by CardCode ) commission
FROM SalesCommission_CTE
    WHERE ItmsGrpCod NOT IN (109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118)
    ORDER BY
        BizProp,
        WhsCode, 
        ItmsGrpCod, 
        ItemCode, 
        CardCode
        ,U_CardCode
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using SQL Server.  WIll dense_rank work in SQL SERVER?

Comment: Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756717/sql-server-how-to-imitate-oracle-keep-dense-rank-query