# Oracle to SQL Server: Convert keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY ...) over (partition by)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2012

Looking to run the following Oracle syntax in SQL server. I know T-SQL not support 'keep' but not sure what to replace it with.

```
MIN( ap_year ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ap_year) OVER 
                    ( PARTITION BY no ) AS first_ap_year
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in _"PVER(partition by e.no)"_?

Comment: Does this help? [SQL Server: how to imitate oracle keep dense_rank query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756717/sql-server-how-to-imitate-oracle-keep-dense-rank-query)

Comment: @GRIV, I'll have a look